# How to calculate value difference to previous date in Excel or Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have following data:

- A - Date (year and month, always the first day, YYYY-MM-DD)
- B - URL
- C - Metric (number)

Amount of dates for url could be different: for the first url there could be seven months, for the second url - only five months.

These data should be placed in a table so i can with a formula calculate the prozentual difference of metric between monthes for the certain url.

The following is an example of the table. If you mean, the table should better look otherwise (transponded, sorted on the other way or so) to enable smart calculation - just say!

```
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
|      A     |   B  |    C   |                 D                |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| Date       | URL  | Metric | Metric Change to previous month  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2019-06-01 | url1 | 1312   |                                  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2019-07-01 | url1 | 1241   |                                  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2019-08-01 | url1 | 5370   |                                  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2019-09-01 | url1 | 6117   |                                  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2019-10-01 | url1 | 5827   |                                  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2019-11-01 | url1 | 4827   |                                  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2019-12-01 | url1 | 5267   |                                  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2020-01-01 | url2 | 7218   |                                  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2020-02-01 | url2 | 6440   |                                  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2020-03-01 | url2 | 5966   |                                  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2020-04-01 | url2 | 5283   |                                  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
| 2020-05-01 | url2 | 6020   |                                  |
+------------+------+--------+----------------------------------+
```

I firstly thought, i calculate the metric's difference of the second month to the first month with the formula like `=c3/c2-1` and get the procentual difference. But then i realized two problems:

1. the first month should be excluded from calculation because there is nothing, what can be compared with the first month's value.
2. there are multiple urls, and the formula must "know", that calculations should appear only applied to same url's metrics.

How can i adjust the original formula and calculate changes to previous months while getting into consideration these two factors?

Comment: have you tried any formula, seems to me that MAXIFS inside a SUMIFS would easily return the correct value.

Comment: Enter formula (excel) in D2 and copy down `=IF(B2<>B1,0,(C2/C1)-1)` Will work if the data is sorted on URL and date. If you want first cell of the URL to be blank then replace 0 with ""

Comment: @NareshBhople It Wokrs Indeed! Thank you!

Comment: Is this for Excel or for Google Sheets? Could you post the solution as an answer?